# Add spring boot maven project as dependency to another project (locally)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am looking to use one SB project as a dependency in another project -- without using a parent pom and locally. I have done this before using a parent pom and specifying modules, but I am looking at splitting up the repo and need to achieve the same without the parent pom.

I have found a few SO posts outlining ways of doing this, but none of them seem to work for me. They all involve `mvn install`ing the artifact so that it's available in the local repo. And that seems to work for me, until it doesn't.

Note: I am working in a corporate environment and I do plan to deploy these jars to our internal Nexus repo, however, I would like to figure out local development first before diving down this route.

My set up is two empty start.spring.io projects (with different names).

```
.
├── test-application
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── java
│           │   └── com
│           │       └── example
│           │           └── testapplication
│           │               ├── TestApplication.java
│           │               └── TestClientConfig.java
│           └── resources
│               └── application.properties
│   
└── test-client
    ├── pom.xml
    └── src
        └── main
            ├── java
            │   └── com
            │       └── example
            │           └── testclient
            │               ├── TestClient.java
            │               └── TestClientApplication.java
            └── resources
                └── application.properties
```

In one project, `test-client`, I define a new class

```java
// TestClient.java

public class TestClient {

    private String value;

    public TestClient(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Just some basic test class that I will make into a bean in my consumer application.

Next, I run `mvn clean install` and verify that it's in my `.m2/repository` folder

[image]

And now in the `test-application`

```xml
//pom.xml

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

IntelliJ auto-imports and everything looks fine, no red.

Next, inside of a new file `TestClientConfig.java` I start implementing my client:

[image]

IntellJ picks up the new classes from the dependency and suggests them. However, when I try to import, things don't work out too well.

It will import the full package name and then not recognize it:
[image]

And I can't add an import statement.

So I am stuck at this point. I have tried finessing some settings in IntelliJ to include the compiled jar as a library or to add a module but nothing really seemed to work fully and those options seemed kind of hacky.

Here's a link to the zip: https://drive.google.com/open?id=13XGVzICO_QHn_ihM7NFtK3GobAxeqLYf

Comment: Do you have `package com.example.testclient;` statement in your `TestClient.java` file? Does IntelliJ IDEA suggest you to [set the package](https://i.imgur.com/HdzYE6M.png)?

Comment: Yeah, of course. The packages are set appropriately, I just left it out of the code snippet

Comment: There may be an issue with the project configuration. If you have both modules in the same project it's better to have the parent pom.xml that will define both modules and have the dependency in the app pom. Then you just import the root pom.xml in IntelliJ IDEA and everything is configured automatically with the dependencies resolved from sources instead of the repository jars. If it still doesn't work, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (the project directory zipped via any file sharing service).

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks for the response. As I had mentioned earlier in the post, I am trying to move away from the multi-module set up as this client will be used across other applications (like opensource)
I will update the original question with a link to the zip

Comment: The jar produced by the client [has no project classes in the standard locations](https://i.imgur.com/rJfZxve.png). They are in `BOOT-INF` instead. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html . You build client as the executable Spring Boot jar, not the regular library, hence the problem.

Comment: thanks! are you saying I need to package it differently in order for it to work? I've done this exact set up using maven modules with a parent pom and didn't run into these issue and unfortunately the explanation you gave is a little too low level for me

Comment: With maven modules IntelliJ IDEA will resolve the dependencies from sources instead of jars. With your setup the dependencies are resolved from jars. The issue is not IDE specific any more. The packaging needs to be changed so that your client build configuration is not inherited from `spring-boot-loader` and is packaged as a normal jar instead, not the spring boot executable jar. The .class files need to be in the root of the jar instead of `BOOT-INF` if you want to depend on this jar in the other projects.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes more sense. Will try and figure this one out. I do have a feeling, though, that my use case here for using spring boot as a sort of client (would be used for API calls) is not necessarily the right use case

Comment: 1. parent pom is (usual, but) not necessary to be in the same repository (it just must be in maven/nexus/...)  ... to date it's quite usual&handy to have an "external parent pom"

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-dependency this seems to correlate with what @CrazyCoder is saying

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Maven modules IntelliJ IDEA will resolve the dependencies from sources instead of jars. With your setup the dependencies are resolved from jars.

The `.class` files need to be in the root of the jar instead of `BOOT-INF` if you want to depend on this jar in the other projects. The classes are in `BOOT-INF` since you are using `spring-boot-loader` application which [builds the executable jar](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html).

[This document](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-dependency) describes how to workaround the problem:

> In order to share classes with another project, the best approach to
>   take is to create a separate jar containing shared classes, then make
>   it a dependency of all modules that rely on them.

```
...
<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

> This will create two jars, one with the suffix exec as an executable
>   jar, and another as a more typical jar that we can include in other
>   projects.

Comment: Yep, that was literally it. Those three lines specifying the `exec` classifier. I managed to find the solution right before i saw this answer. Thanks for the speedy responses.